# HttpResult(HttpStatusCode.NoContent) creates response "OK"

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, servicestack

I am using .NET MVC.

When I return `new HttpResult(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);` the object that is created has a status code = 200:

```
{ServiceStack.Common.Web.HttpResult}
    AllowsPartialResponse: false
    ContentType: null
    FileInfo: null
    Headers: Count = 0
    IsPartialRequest: false
    Options: Count = 0
    RequestContext: null
    Response: NoContent
    ResponseFilter: {ServiceStack.Common.Web.HttpResponseFilter}
    ResponseStream: null
    ResponseText: null
    Status: 200
    StatusCode: OK
    StatusDescription: null
    Template: null
    View: null
```

Erm.. what?

Comment: Looks like you are using ServiceStack.  Where is the service being hosted, IIS or some other service?  That may have an effect on the status code.

Comment: @rycornell It's being hosted on IIS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify a status description in the constructor if you want to use the overloaded constructor that takes a `HttpStatusCode`

If you look at the code for [HttpResult](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Common/Web/HttpResult.cs) you can see that the constructor you are calling is this:

```
public HttpResult(object response) : this(response, null) {}
```

The `HttpStatusCode` object you are passing in is actually being used as the response (any object can be a response). There is another constructor that you should be using here:

`public HttpResult(HttpStatusCode statusCode, string statusDescription)`

i.e.

```
new HttpResult(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, "No Content");
```

Comment: Good spot, Mike!  Thanks.